# Tweepy and Python: how to list all followers

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

With tweepy in Python I'm looking for a way to list all followers from one account, with username and number of followers.
Now I can obtain the list of all ids in this way:

```
ids = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name="username").pages():
    ids.extend(page)
    time.sleep(1)
```

but with this list of ids I can't obtain username and number of followers of every id, because the rate limit exceed...
How I can complete this code?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the REST API, your are allowed [180 queries every 15 minutes](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting), and I guess the Streaming API has a similar limitation. You do not want to come too close to this limit, since your application will eventually get blocked even if you do not strictly hit it.
Since your problem has something to do with the rate limit, you should put a sleep in your `for` loop. I'd say a `sleep(4)` should be enough, but it's mostly a matter of trial and error there, try to change the value and see for yourself.

Something like

```
sleeptime = 4
pages = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="username").pages()


while True:
    try:
        page = next(pages)
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
    except tweepy.TweepError: #taking extra care of the "rate limit exceeded"
        time.sleep(60*15) 
        page = next(pages)
    except StopIteration:
        break
   for user in page:
       print(user.id_str)
       print(user.screen_name)
       print(user.followers_count)
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply! The problem is not in that for, this give me a list of all ids of the followers. The problem is to use that ids, and create a list of username ad relative followers, every try give me a rate limit error

Comment: So, what you want to do is get all the id of the followers of a given account, and then for each of them send a request to get the username and the number of followers?

Comment: this is a possibile solution... or maybe there is a way to make it in the same loop, I can't find one. Thanks again

Comment: `api.followers` will return a list of user objects, each of which will contain their id, screen_name and followers_count. Use that instead of only getting their ids with `api.followers_id`.